# How to group a list into inclusive sequential n-length sublists?

Tags: python, list, sublist

To be more precise:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
def group_me(A, 4):
    # magic goes here

---> [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def group_me(array,length):
    return [array[n:n+length] for n in range(0,len(array)-length+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
def group_me(A, n):
    return [A[i:i+n] for i in range(len(A)-n+1)]


>>> group_me([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4)
[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]
```